# IE10's localStorage is broken?

Tags: internet-explorer, ccleaner, local-storage

I recently ran CCleaner to clean up my laptop. Since then, every time any site tries to access `window.localStorage`, the following error appears:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

It also does not appear in the properties list if I "watch" the `window` object.

Interestingly, `sessionStorage` is still present and works just fine.

Is it possible that CCleaner deleted a file that was critical to IE10's use of `localStorage`? If so, is it fixable just by creating the relevant file/directory?

To give an idea of how critical this issue is, I cannot log in to StackExchange! Half of my websites don't work anymore so I can't work, and overall I'm basically screwed. Help!

Comment: As you can see I have succesfully logged in, but to do so I had to disabled Protected Mode. So I guess my question is "What exactly does Protected Mode do?"

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1412083/552792

Comment: did you got any operative answer ? I also cleaned my PC with CCLeaner and got burnt ! Two days looking for solution!!

Answer (score 9):

I had this same exact problem. To solve it, go into:

Internet Options -> Browsing History -> Delete:

Make sure to check all options except the very first one (Preserve Favorite website data).

We were able to fix, then reproduce this issue by using CCleaner again, then fix again.

Go to this site for more information: http://grekai.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/localstorage-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/

Comment: In addition I had to restore default advanced settings.